# Ways to store a JTree and reconstruct in XML

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree

I have a JTree which is populated with database information, and I want to be able to store selected nodes such that I can recreate this tree in an XML file.

The output XML file also has additional attributes which are not simply database properties. Each  node has a "specAttribute" attribute with some unique value specified by user. Currently, I take each selected node in the original tree and add it to an arraylist of properties class, where the properties class contains the path of selected node, as well as special characteristic.

However, I am having trouble generating a tree with just the path of the selected nodes. How can I do this and also assign attributes properly to the respective node?

Comment: A JTree is just a view on a data model, which is what you need to serialize. What does your TreeModel look like?

Comment: Right, I use DataBaseMetaData to get schemas, iterate over those and get tables, iterate over those and get columns. It is the default TreeModel.